# Linear Layout not showing some elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to show three elements search box, google map and one button in vertical order. The problem is only search box and map show and below this no button is displayed. I have set orientation as vertical. Below is my code, please suggest any solution.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="mypackage">

   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    />

  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   tools:context="mypackage" />


   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this make **`ScrollView`** as your root layout like below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        tools:context="mypackage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="mypackage" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Or Provide weight to your fragments as per your requirement like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="mypackage">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="mypackage" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`SupportMapFragment` is suggested to be set with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, so a linear layout with another view below the map won't work. You can achieve that by using a relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="mypackage">

   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Button" />

  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_below="@id/place_autocomplete"
   android:layout_above="@id/button2"
   tools:context="mypackage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I had set android:layout_height="wrap_content" for SupportMapFragment, but why this happened ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the underlying code of `SupportMapFragment`, but this is the implementation suggested by Google in their docs.